# Can a control in user control be validated by validator outside the user control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a user control which chooses to show TextBox or DropdownList according to other configuration.

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="CustomRelationshipDropDown.ascx.vb" Inherits="CustomRelationshipDropDown" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Codebehind:

```
<ValidationProperty("Value")>
<SupportsEventValidation()>
Partial Class CustomRelationshipDropDown
    Inherits UserControl

    Public Property Value() As String
        Get
            If GetList("RelationshipList") Is Nothing Then
                Return TextBox1.Text
            Else
                Return DropDownList1.SelectedValue
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            If GetList("RelationshipList") Is Nothing Then
                TextBox1.Text = Value
            Else
                DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim list As List(Of String) = GetList("RelationshipList")

        If list IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each item In list
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(item)
            Next
            DropDownList1.Visible = True
            TextBox1.Visible = False
        Else
            DropDownList1.Visible = False
            TextBox1.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Another page uses that user control and I want to have a RequiredValidator to validate the text box.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <div>
        <uc1:CustomRelationshipDropDown ID="CustomRelationshipDropDown1" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="CustomRelationshipDropDown1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</form>
```

When I click Button1, the second validator didn't find the second text box is empty.

[image]

How should I modify CustomRelationshipDropDown so that external validator can validate the textbox inside it?

Comment: did you try  ControlToValidate="CustomRelationshipDropDown1.TextBox1" ?

Comment: @ZivWeissman no, it doesn't work in this way. Besides I updated my question. My user control shows text box or drop down list according to certain logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
 <div>
        <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="WebUserControl1$TextBox2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator3" ControlToValidate="WebUserControl1$DropDownList1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 </div>
```

Where my controller is simple as :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Also tried to random Visible = false each, and it works.

Comment: You just solved a problem I have spent hours looking for an answer to... thanks!

Comment: @AlBelmondo np, glad to help, if you want another advice that will save u a lot of hours - don't use webforms XD